# Rational Solutions to Systems of Quadratic with Integer Coeffcients

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like prove there are no rational solution to  ${2 u^2 - v^2 =34, u^2 - w^2 =34}$. (A hint suggests transforming the equations and working modulo 8.)

I think I need to make sure the denominators are odd so that 4 divides the squared values. Then ultimately I may be able to get to a mod 8 set of congruences from which I can draw some conclusions.

Is this a reasonable approach and how do I find an appropriate transform in order to get started?

Comment: Why not write them out as fractions [in lowest terms], clear the denominators, and then work in the integers?